# Improving speed of GeoPandas dissolve

Tags: python, performance, geopandas, dissolve

I am trying to dissolve grid spaces by category using GeoPandas' `dissolve` function, but it doesn't finish after hours of running and I want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong and/or there isn't some way to speed it up.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
outputData = gp.GeoDataFrame(outputData[['category','geometry']])
outputData['geometry'] = outputData['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
outputDataFrame = outputData.dissolve(by='category')
```

Here's the breakdown: I've got a Dataframe called `outputData` with many variables/columns, so I limit it to the two I need and convert it into a geoDataFrame.   In order to use the geometry column, I need to apply `wtk.loads` else I get an error about it being a `str` type.  There are 12 values in the category column (0-11) and around 200,000 rows in the DataFrame.

I've run dissolve before (e.g. to get region boundaries from counties) but never on so many geometries.  I'm thinking that because in this case the geometries are all simple and non-overlapping (a grid) there may be a better way to combine them.  But if `dissolve` is just `groupby` + `unary_union`, then I don't know what could be better than that.

Is this a known unsolvable problem with large datasets or are there any tricks to speed it up significantly (e.g., by setting an option or using a different library/function)?

Comment: Are you using a recent version of geopandas and its dependencies?

Comment: Does the same code work on a smaller dataset with similar characteristics?

Comment: I was using geopandas 0.4.0, so I upgraded to 0.5.0.  After doing that, I was able to dissolve the first 500 rows in 0.10 seconds.  If it were linear timing, the full dataset would complete in about 40s, but it hasn't finished after many minutes.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* I am the developer of the [Geofileops](https://github.com/geofileops/geofileops) library.

Probably slightly too late... but because I also had issues doing dissolves on large datasets I wrote a function that uses GeoPandas under the hood but contains several optimizations to speed this up for large inputs: [`geofileops.dissolve`](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.dissolve.html)

The input file should be in GeoPackage (or shapefile).

Minimal code sample:

```
import geofileops as gfo

# Convert input file to geopackage
gfo.copy_layer(input_path, input_gpkg_path)

gfo.dissolve(
    input_path=...,
    output_path=...,
    groupby_columns=["category"],
    explodecollections=False,
)
```